# Laravel blade adding a class for a particular uri using a wildcard

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to make a menu but some of my pages have custom uris based on a random string

like */page/show/hn87qh208h2u3gf8o7g87*

I've tried a few various implementations, like the one below, but its not working. Has anyone come across this before?

I'm lead to believe from searching that the wildcard would work within blade like it does in php, but its seems not, it could be because i'm using the latest version and its been removed/changed maybe?

```
{{ Request::is('/page/show/*') ? 'active' : '' }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a name to your particular route as below:

Suppose you have route as below:

`Route::get('page/show/{id}', 'Path\To\Your\Controller\Name@methodName');`

Rewrite it as :

`Route::get('page/show/{id}', ['as' => 'show-page','uses' => 'Path\To\Your\Controller\Name@methodName'])`

OR

`Route::get('page/show/{id}', 'Path\To\Your\Controller\Name@methodName')->nane('show-page');`

In view file change the code as below:

`{{ Request::route()->getName() == 'show-page' ? 'active' : '' }}`

I hope may this will help you.